# Creating a fail-safe using Amazon Route 53 & EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vps, amazon-route53

I currently own a VPS and recently had a network outage which meant that my sites were down for almost 2 hours. Since i did face this problem, I really need to have a fail-safe setup to ensure that my websites & applications dont have downtime.

My current server scenario:
 - 1 VPS with 2 name servers.
 - All domains owned and controlled by me. No reseller accounts on vps.

How do I setup an EC2 with Route 53 using Rsync and a mysql cron to run a fail-safe?

I know this is probably going to be a tough job to do, but if someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Also since all my sites are live, I really do not want to play around with my server a lot.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does your stack look like ? Mysql is the only dynamic data ?

Comment: @Rico - yup, there are a bunch of image files as well as pdf's, but they are already on s3 using cloudfront. Not really worried about those.